# Spring WebFlow - business logic in view-state or action-state

Tags: spring-webflow

What is the best place to call the business logic in? I have the  following requirements.

1). Get the search criteria from user

2). If the current user is trying search for unauthorized results throw business exception

3). Retrieve results

4). If number of results==0, go to search page again and put a message.

5). If number of results>limit, go to search page again and put a message.

6). Go to showresults page.

This is what I have so far...

```
<flow....>
      <on-start>
          <evaluate expression="appConfig.setUpSupportData()" result="flowScope.supportData"/>  
      </on-start>
      <view-state id="searchHome" view="searchHome" model="searchCriteria">
           <transition on="search" to="doSearch"/>
      </view-state> 

      <action-state id="doSearch">
             <evaluate expression="searchUtil.getSearchResults(flowScope.searchCriteria)" result="flowScope.personList"/>
             <evaluate expression="searchUtil.showSearchResults(flowScope.personList, flowRequestContext)" >
                     <attribute name="name" value="expression2"/>
             </evaluate>
             <transition on="expression2.yes" to="showSearchResults"/>
             <transition on="expression2.no" to="searchHome"/>
     </action-state>
     <view-state id="showSearchResults"></view-state>
</flow>
```

My question is, should I be calling the getSearchResults() method in action-stae or in view-state="showSearchResults"? If I call the method in action-stae, I have to put the search results in flowscope so that second view can get the results - I am worried about memory in this scenario. If I call the method in second view- on-entry, I can put the personList in viewscope but how do I handle cases 2,4 and 5?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You've answered part of your own question already:

- Using an action-state to invoke business logic gives you a bit more control on how you react to different outcomes: go here on-exception, go somewhere else if everything is fine, and so on. The downside being that you need to put data in a longer lived scope (flow scope) to make it available to the view-state.
- Using a view-state allows you to use a short lived scope (view scope or request scope) by retrieving the data using a render-action or entry-action, but doesn't give you much control when it comes to processing action outcomes.

Selecting between the two is a bit of a trade-of. If the search results can get very big, using a short lived scope to reduce memory load as much as possible is probably an important concern, so you would use a view-state. In other scenarios an action-state might be more appropriate.

One alternative approach is to introduce an application controller (invoked from the flow) that calls the business logic and returns an object that contains several things:

- the search results
- a potential info/warning message to display

You could then use a view-state and the view would be able to simply pick up the search results and info/warning message from the result object and display it.